# How do I run junit in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

[image: code screenshot]

I have done everything as mentioned here: https://www.javatpoint.com/junit-tutorial
I use sublime text 3 and have included the error message as a image.
`junit4-4.8.2.jar` and `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` are present in `C:\Junit`.
the javatpoint code file is in `C:\Junit_workspace\junittesting`.

Am I doing something wrong or is it simply not possible in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Your classpath isn’t working, however it is you’re setting it up, but you don’t include that part.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I cannot find the CLASSPATH in environment variables. what should I add there?

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven or Gradle to manage your project. They'll allow you to specify the library dependencies you have and manage the classpath.

Note also that the latest version of JUnit is 5.x.

Can't say I've ever used Sublime really, but is there also a reason you're not using an IDE like IntelliJ?